# How to improve performance on a function that operates on two arrays in clojure

Tags: clojure, micro-optimization, mathematical-optimization

I have a set of a small number of functions.  Two functions perform a mathematical overlay operation (defined on http://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-concepts-layer-modes.html, but a little down -- just search for "overlay" to find the math) in different ways.  Now, this operation is something that Gimp does very quickly, in under a second, but I can't seem to optimize my code to get anything like remotely similar time.

(My application is a GUI application to help me see and compare various overlay combinations of a large number of files.  The Gimp layer interface actually makes it rather difficult to just pick two images to overlay, then pick a different two, etc.)

Here is the code:

```
(set! *warn-on-reflection* true )

(defn to-8-bit [v]
  (short (* (/ v 65536) 256)))

(defn overlay-sample [base-p over-p]
  (to-8-bit 
    (* (/ base-p 65536) 
       (+ base-p
          (* (/ (* 2 over-p) 65536)
             (- 65536 base-p))))))

(defn overlay-map [^shorts base ^shorts over]
  (let [ovl (time (doall (map overlay-sample ^shorts base ^shorts over)))]
    (time (into-array Short/TYPE ovl))))

(defn overlay-array [base over]
  (let [ovl (time (amap base
                        i
                        r
                        (int (overlay-sample (aget r i)
                                             (aget over i)))))]
    ovl))
```

overlay-map and overlay-array do the same operation in different ways.  I've written other versions of this operation, too.  However, overlay-map is, by far, the fastest I have.

base and over, in both functions, are 16-bit integer arrays.  The actual size of each is 1,276,800 samples (an 800 x 532 image with 3 samples per pixel).  The end result should be a single array of the same, but scaled down to 8-bits.

My results from the (time) operation are pretty consistent.  overlay-map runs the actual mathematical operation in about 16 or 17 seconds, then spends another 5 seconds copying the resulting sequence back into an integer array.

overlay-array takes about 111 seconds.

I've done a lot of reading about using arrays, type hints, etc, but my Java-Array-Only operation is amazingly slow!  amap, aget, etc was all supposed to be fast, but I have read the code and there is nothing that looks like a speed optimization there, and my results are consistent.  I've even tried other computers and seen roughly the same difference.

Now, 16-17 seconds is, actually rather painful at this data set, but I've been caching the results so that I can easily switch back and forth.  The same operation would take an atrociously long time if I increased the size of the dataset to anything like a full-size image (4770x3177).  And, there's other operations I want to be doing, too.

So, any suggestions on how to speed this up?  What am I missing here?

UPDATE: I just made the entire project pertaining to this code public, so you can see the current version entire script I am using for speed tests at https://bitbucket.org/savannidgerinel/hdr-darkroom/src/62a42fcf6a4b/scripts/speed_test.clj .  Feel free to download it and try it on your own gear, but obviously change the image file paths before running it.

Comment: Have you tried type hinting `base` and `over` with `^shorts`? And get rid of your `^Integer` type hint, it's not doing anything.

Comment: Does ^Integer do nothing because of its location or because it is not a valid type hint?  I assume that ^shorts, being plural, applies to arrays?

Comment: `^Integer` does something, it's just not helpful here (you can time it with and without it, if you'd like; I'd recommend doing that always, as well as `(set! *warn-on-reflection* true)`). `^shorts` is a type hint for a primitive array of shorts. I'd time it and see if it helps.

Comment: I'm not able to modify overlay-array (some ClassCastException between integer and short that I haven't figured out), but I did make the type  hinting change to overlay-map.  Time seems to have consistently dropped to 13 seconds for the processing and about 300 microseconds for the copy into an array.  Much improved, but still not where I need it to be.

Comment: No, 1.2.1.  Would 1.3 add a feature that would help?

Comment: Oh yes, absolutely. You can type-hint primitive ^long and ^double now!

Comment: Yeah, but I'm not needing to.  The data is at most 16-bits.  32-bits per channel would be excessive for every use case I can think of, and the files would get to be really, really huge.  Also, had to drop back to doing (into-array Integer/TYPE) instead of Short/TYPE because the WriteableRaster class does not accept shorts.  And may have ended up copying the data again even if it did.

Comment: So, I've done all of the type hinting I possibly could.  I also did additional work trying to reduce copies by working directly on the arrays returned by Raster.getPixels().  Best performance is still 13 seconds.  My next try, once I can manage to get the compilation working correctly, is a straight-up Java class that does this.  After that, C+JNI.

Comment: Try posting on the Clojure Google groups mailing list–more people who might be able to better help you post there. I haven't done much optimization using Clojure yet, but if I find some time tomorrow I'll take a closer look.

Answer (score 1):

Since your functions are purely mathematical, you might want to check out memoize

```
(def fast-overlay (memoize overlay-sample))

(time (fast-overlay 1000 2000))
"Elapsed time: 1.279 msecs"
(time (fast-overlay 1000 2000))
"Elapsed time: 0.056 msecs"
```

What's happening here is the arguments are being cached as the key and the return is the value. Where the value has already been computed, the value is returned rather than the function executed.

Comment: I tried this.  Performance actually went down so far that I aborted the test after it ran triple the original time.  With two different 16-bit values going into the function, I would be surprised if I had more than a very trivial number of repeats.